# How to convert PNG image binary string to base64 without writing it to disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I successfully passed an image as binary string out of puppeteers `page.evaluate()` function back to node.js using:

```js
async function getBinaryString(url) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const response = await window.fetch(url)
        const data = await response.blob();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = () => reject('Error occurred while reading binary string');
    });
}
```

I am able to save it with:

```js
fs.writeFileSync(“image.png”, new Buffer.from(binaryString, "binary"), function (err) { });
```

But now I wish to convert this `PNG` image to `base64` without saving it to file first because I will upload it to a different server. If I save it to file, I can do the following:

```js
function base64Encode(file) {
    const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);                 
    return new Buffer.from(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

How do I skip the file saving part and get proper `base64` data for my `PNG`? 
I tried to pass binary string to `new Buffer.from(binaryString).toString('base64')` but I was unable to save it as a working `PNG`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "but I was unable to save it as a working `PNG`." If you're saving a base64 string to a file, it's not going to to be a PNG any longer.

Comment: I used an online converter to substitute a 3rd party endpoint that I normally send PNG image to. Both the endpoint and the web converter failed to convert my base64 string back to an image. I have not tried to display it in HTML yet, will test this next but I expect it not to be a valid image.

Comment: Did you already try `Buffer.from(binaryString, 'binary').toString('base64')`?

Comment: @Jacob D'oh! That was it, I forgot the “binary” param, it works now and is valid PNG. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t really warrant answering my own question but @Jacob reminded me that I forgot to try:

```js
new Buffer.from(binaryString, 'binary').toString('base64');
```

with a `"binary"` parameter, which solved the issue and `PNG` was correctly formatted again when going from `base64` to file or to image in a browser.

Maybe the code in question can be reused by some other puppeteer user, it took me a while to come up with and find pieces across the web.